# Loader does not cover the entire page

Tags: css, angular

If a scroll appears on the page and the page scrolls down, then when you call the function to display the loader, it will cover only the top of the page. How to make the loader cover the entire page even if the page is scrolled to the site footer?

**Any page:**

```
<app-loader [loader]="loading"></app-loader>
...
```

**loader.component.html:**

```
<div class="load-container" *ngIf="loader">
  <div class="load-speeding-wheel"></div>
</div>
```

**loader.component.ts:**

```
@Input() loader: boolean = false;
```

**layout.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <app-toolbar (sideNavToggled)="snav.toggle()"></app-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" [style.marginTop.px]="toolBarHeight">
    <mat-sidenav #snav class="sidenav" [(mode)]="sideNavMode" [(opened)]="sideNavOpened">
      <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content> 
      <main class="main-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </main>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

**loader.css:**

```
.load-container {
    width           : 100%;
    height          : 100%;
    text-align      : center;
    position        : absolute;
    left            : 0;
    top             : 0;
    display         : flex;
    flex-direction  : column;
    align-items     : center;
    justify-content : center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index         : 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way could be using:

```
container {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Damn, just had to add `position: fixed;`))

Comment: :D Glad i could help plus remember to set high z-index to make sure it overrides any other element on the screen and overflow hidden to avoid scroll bars

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with width: 100vw and height: 100vh for the load-container (instead of 100%}?

Comment: Tried, there is no difference, the only thing that appears is the bottom scroll.